# Haskell private records like in OCaml

Tags: haskell, record

In an OCaml module signature I can write:

```
type monotype = private {
  monotype_free_variables: StringSet.t Lazy.t;
  monotype_description: monotype_description;
}
```

(Note the use of `private`.)

This allows the code importing my module to pattern match against fields like `monotype_description` but will not allow code importing my module to construct the record.

Can I write code with similar access permission in Haskell? I’d like to pattern match against a `monotypeDescription` field without allowing record construction.

I’m aware that a `PatternSynonyms` language extension exists, but I don’t know how to use it. I’d also prefer a simpler solution if available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your module:

```
module MyMod (MyType(), myGetter, j, n) where -- the key is that MyData is not exported

data MyType = MyData (Maybe Int) String

myGetter (MyData x _) = x

j = MyData (Just 5) "abc"

n = MyData Nothing "abc"
```

Elsewhere, to do the pattern matching:

```
f x | Just i <- myGetter x = show i
    | otherwise            = "nope"
```

Now `f j` will be `"5"` and `f n` will be `"nope"`.

Alternatively, with the `ViewPatterns` extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}
f (myGetter -> Just i) = show i
f _                    = "nope"
```

Comment: What is the `f x | Just i <- myGetter x` syntax called? Is it composable with another boolean condition with `&&`?

Comment: `ViewPatterns` is great. It allows my consuming code to pattern match on whatever it wants which is simpler than asking my producing code on all my types to define a pattern with `PatternSynonyms`.

Comment: @Calebmer It's `PatternGuards`. It's either a part of the new standard or it's just a on-by-default extension. You compose guards with `,`, not `&&`.

Comment: @HTNW [Yes, pattern guards were added to Haskell 2010!](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#dx8-46011)

Answer (score 7):

You can't match against the fields without also allowing at least record update (you either import the field or not). I think the restriction is more because there isn't an obvious syntax for importing only accessors...

The proper solution is really to use `PatternSynonyms`. You'll want a uni-directional pattern:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
module MyModule ( Monotype(Monotype) ) where

import Data.Set

data Monotype = MT (Set String) String

pattern Monotype :: Set String -> String -> Monotype
pattern Monotype { monotype_free_variables, monotype_description }
  <- MT monotype_free_variables monotype_description
```

Now, you can match against `Monotype { monotype_free_variables, monotype_description }` but you can't construct it:

```
λ> Monotype { monotype_free_variables = f1, monotype_description = f2 } = m1
λ> Monotype f1 f2 = m1
λ> m3 = Monotype { monotype_free_variables = mempty, monotype_description = "" }
<interactive>:3:6: error:
    • non-bidirectional pattern synonym ‘Monotype’ used in an expression
    • In the expression:
        Monotype
          {monotype_free_variables = mempty, monotype_description = ""}
      In an equation for ‘m3’:
          m3
            = Monotype
                {monotype_free_variables = mempty, monotype_description = ""}
λ> m3 = Monotype mempty ""

<interactive>:4:6: error:
    • non-bidirectional pattern synonym ‘Monotype’ used in an expression
    • In the expression: Monotype mempty ""
      In an equation for ‘m3’: m3 = Monotype mempty ""
```

Comment: Wow it never occurred to me that exporting a field would allow record update.  Yikes.

Comment: I frequently use the pattern `module MyModule (Monotype, monotypeDescription)` to export an accessor but I had assumed that would not allow my consumer to update the record. Is that not true?

Comment: That is not true. ‘m { monotypeDescription = d1 }’ updates m even though it’s constructor is not exported.